# AppleScript Yosemite open directory

Tags: applescript, finder

Since upgrading to Yosemite I can get finder to open a folder:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open ("/Users/username/Desktop/testfolder" as POSIX file)
end tell
```

I cant find info how to make this simple thing work again.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am away from my Yosemite Mac at the Mo.

But try:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open ((POSIX file "/Users/username/Desktop/testfolder") as alias)
end tell
```

Comment: I was going to propose the same, which works on Mavericks, I see no reason why it won't work on Yosemite.

Comment: I just checked a different machine, and it does work. It seems that my machine has a problem. Thanks for the help!